# C++ vs Java for simple graphics

Tags: java, c++, graphics

I want to develop a program that topologically sorts the vertices of a directed graph as a way to practice some of the graphing data structures and algorithms I'm learning in algorithms class. To make things a bit more interesting, I also want to add some graphics to display the results of the topological sort, something like in image b) below.

[image]

I'm familiar with the basics of both C++ and Java, so I'll be choosing one of those languages to work in. First, what are the pros and cons of working in each language for a project like this? Second, what kind of libraries should I look at to implement these kinds of simple graphic? I know that there are lots of choices out there, but I'd like to choose something that I might use again in the future and isn't total overkill for a task like this.

Thanks

Comment: Easiest is to use some existing graph display thing. Free association: I seem to remember that DOxygen uses some simple 3rd party thing.

Comment: Really easy mighj be to use something like SVG,

Comment: Flagged - Opinion Based

Comment: @RichardCritten Is this not the place for such a question? If so, where should I post?

Comment: i believe both languages will have nice and useful tools and libraries.i recommend you to read comparison between these two languages, and choose one which fits your need better. alternatively go with one which you want to practice more

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly prefer Java over C++. yes C++ is core but Java provides over 30,000 classes and interfaces. you get the Graphics class in awt package.

Graphics class is the abstract base class for all graphics contexts that allow an application to draw onto components that are realized on various devices, as well as onto off-screen images.

The Graphics class plays two different but related roles within the abstract windowing toolkit (AWT). First, it maintains the graphics context, which consists of all of the information that will affect the outcome of a graphics operation. This includes the drawing color, the font, and the location and dimensions of the clipping rectangle (the region in which graphics can be drawn). More importantly, the graphics context defines the destination for the graphics operations about to be discussed (destinations include components and images).

All the best

Comment: If you need any more help you can always contact me on gmail or here itself.

Comment: AWT seems quite large. Do you have any suggestions regarding how I can sort through the sheer volume of material out there? Should I just start from "AWT 101" or is there someplace more specific I can start reading from?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html.                 I hope this will surely help you out, yes AWT is huge and still used when it comes to desktop apps. Try the link. Best luck Adam.

Comment: I'll have a look. Thanks!